# Setting mean value of Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

At each round of an algorithm, I need to sample a fixed number of participants, say `100` out of a total population of `500` to participate in the algorithm. The selection of participants should be based on `poisson subsampling` such that each participants is drawn with subsampling probability of `100/500` .

If I run the algorithm for 10 rounds, what would be the best strategy for setting the `lambda` to draw the 100 participants at each round ?

Comment: In each round, each participant is selected independently with probability $p$. No matter what $p$ you choose, you cannot guarantee that exactly 100 will be selected. What do you do if there are more or less than 100 selected and what criteria do you want to decide the best algorithm?

Comment: @JohnL
At each round of the algorithm, I set lambda randomly, then perform a poisson subsampling to draw participants from the population. In most cases, the sampled participants are less than 100, so I re-perform poisson subsampling again with different random lambda, and keep subsampling like this until I get the 100 participants.

If it happens that more than 100 participants are drawn in a single round, I take only the first 100

I'm just wondering if there is a better strategy to set lambda at each sampling round other than random so I make sure that the entire population is covered

Comment: it's not good to take the first 100 because the people with lower numbers have a higher chance of being selected. If you get 120, then you should try to sample 100 from those 120. If you get less than 100, for example 90, then you can keep those 90 and get another sample of 10 to complete the total of 100. Then you may have to keep doing this many times until you get the right number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint @JohnL, one more thing please, 
any suggestion or strategy to set lambda at each sampling round ?